# Kohana 404 error: Requested URL not found

Tags: php, url, http-status-code-404, kohana

.
Hi everyone,

I'm working on a website for a school project.
Recently I've purchased me own webspace at Biberbit.com and wanted to upload my website.
When I upload it I see the following error on screen:

```
Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

My project uses the Kohana framework version 3.3.1
I already have the .htaccess file and the filenames/directory names are all lower case.
I am using the default route:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Originally I thought it might have been the default_url in the bootstrap.php file so I've changed those lines to this:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/',
    'index_file' => FALSE,
));
```

I've looked for the solution on multiple websites and couldn't find one that works for me.
Can anyone think of something that I might be missing?
I'm also using `URL::site()` for my links so I don't think that's causing it.

You can check the error and/or website at http://www.biberbit.com

**EDIT:** 
.htaccess as requested

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: Can you add the .htaccess?

Comment: @kingkero I think I spotted what's wrong in the .htaccess at the installation directory.

Comment: Does it work when you change the `RewriteBase`?

Comment: @kingkero No, It's set to "/" but it does not seem to fix the 404. Still it's good to have it set properly.

Comment: 1 thing is confusing me: When I connect to the server with my FTP client, it sends me to /, after which I go to domains/biberbit.com/public_html, which is where my code is. Is this irrelevant?

Comment: Yes. Your webroot is under .../public_html/, this is only important when you link to the .htpasswd for example

Comment: My welcome file for instance is called Welcome.php and has the class Controller_Welcome, is this correct according to kohana?

Answer (score 0):

The `base_url` is set wrong, it should be empty (as you are on the web root). Also depending on whether or not you have Linux, filenames **must not** be all lowercase but however you use them in the code. So `Welcome.php` and not `welcome.php` for the default controller.

Comment: Weird thing is, I originally tried the empty base_url, so it would have to be the filenames. I'll check it and come back to you with the results. The name in the file url is always lowercase, but in the classname it's Controller_Welcome for welcome.php.

Comment: I've changed the filenames to reflect the classnames and emptied the base_url string, but it's still giving me the 404.

Comment: I'm sorry, but with correct filenames and properly set `base_url` it should work ..

Answer (score 0):

`Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on this server.` exception is usually thrown when Kohana couldn't find corresponding action method to process a request.

Make sure you have `Controller_Welcome` class and `action_index` method in it.

Also you can inspect your Exception traceback and find what exactly caused an Exception. Most likely you'll see Exeption in `SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Controller.php` file in `if(!method_exists(...))` block.